# How to order object in v-for to stay on top Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, if-statement, vuejs2, vuex, v-for

I have an expansion panel and a `v-for` on it. I want to keep the panel with the same id as the logged-in user on top, and the others render last. My code is like it now:

```
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel v-for="(sign, index) in demandSignatures" :key="index">
    <v-expansion-panel-header
      @click="dataEdit(sign)"
      :hide-actions="userID !== sign.userEid"
      :disabled="userID !== sign.userEid"
      >
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="1"></v-col>
        <v-col cols="4">
          {{ sign.userFullName }}
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <span
            v-if="sign.signatureStatus === 'Accepted'"
            class="text-success"
            >امضا شده</span
            >
          <span
            v-else-if="sign.signatureStatus === 'Rejected'"
            class="text-danger"
            >رد شده</span
            >
          <span
            v-else-if="sign.signatureStatus === 'pending'"
            class="text-warning"
            >در انتظار تایید</span
            >
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content v-if="userID === sign.userEid">
      <v-divider />
      <v-card-text class="mt-3">
        <v-textarea
          label="توضیحات"
          v-model="description"
          outlined
          dense
          ></v-textarea>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions class="mx-4 justify-end d-flex">
        <v-btn
          class="me-2"
          icon
          small
          @click="signForm(sign.eid, 'Accepted', acceptText)"
          >
          <v-icon small color="teal">mdi-draw-pen</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn
          class="ms-2"
          icon
          small
          @click="signForm(sign.eid, 'Rejected', rejText)"
          >
          <v-icon small color="red">mdi-close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
      <v-divider />
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
    <v-expansion-panel-content v-else></v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

I want to keep the panel with this condition `v-if="userID === sign.user-id` on top

Can anyone help with it?

Comment: Do you mean that if the loop item's id is equal to the login user's id, then that panel should be on the top?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `demandSignatures` data by plucking the item whose id is equal to `userID` and put it in the first position. You can do this job on the `mounted` hook.

Here is the working demo-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-expansion-panels>
          <v-expansion-panel v-for="(sign, index) in demandSignatures" :key="sign.userEid">
            <v-expansion-panel-header
              @click="dataEdit(sign)"
              :hide-actions="userID !== sign.userEid"
              :disabled="userID !== sign.userEid"
              >
              <v-row>
                <v-col cols="1"></v-col>
                <v-col cols="4">
                  {{ sign.userFullName }}
                </v-col>
                <v-col>
                  <span
                    v-if="sign.signatureStatus === 'Accepted'"
                    class="text-success"
                    >امضا شده</span
                    >
                  <span
                    v-else-if="sign.signatureStatus === 'Rejected'"
                    class="text-danger"
                    >رد شده</span
                    >
                  <span
                    v-else-if="sign.signatureStatus === 'pending'"
                    class="text-warning"
                    >در انتظار تایید</span
                    >
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-expansion-panel-header>
            <v-expansion-panel-content v-if="userID === sign.userEid">
              <v-divider />
              <v-card-text class="mt-3">
                <v-textarea
                  label="توضیحات"
                  v-model="description"
                  outlined
                  dense
                  ></v-textarea>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions class="mx-4 justify-end d-flex">
                <v-btn
                  class="me-2"
                  icon
                  small
                  @click="signForm(sign.eid, 'Accepted', acceptText)"
                  >
                  <v-icon small color="teal">mdi-draw-pen</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                <v-btn
                  class="ms-2"
                  icon
                  small
                  @click="signForm(sign.eid, 'Rejected', rejText)"
                  >
                  <v-icon small color="red">mdi-close</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
              <v-divider />
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
            <v-expansion-panel-content v-else></v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>
        </v-expansion-panels>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data() {
          return {
            userID: 3,
            description: null,
            demandSignatures: [{
                userEid: 1,
                userFullName: "I am not equal to userID",
                signatureStatus: "Accepted"
              },
              {
                userEid: 2,
                userFullName: "I am not equal to userID",
                signatureStatus: "pending"
              },
              {
                userEid: 3,
                userFullName: "I am equal to userID",
                signatureStatus: "Rejected"
              },
              {
                userEid: 4,
                userFullName: "I am not equal to userID",
                signatureStatus: "Rejected"
              },
            ],
          };
        },
        mounted() {
          this.reOrder();
        },
        methods: {
          reOrder() {
            // Find the index of item who match with userID
            let index = this.demandSignatures.findIndex(
              (item) => item.userEid == this.userID,
            );
            // If item found
            if (index != -1) {
              // save it in some local variable
              let item = this.demandSignatures[index];
              // remove it from its current position
              this.demandSignatures.splice(index, 1);
              // and put it at the first position
              this.demandSignatures.unshift(item);
            }
          },
          dataEdit() {},
          signForm() {},
        },
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```